# What does Backward Power flow mean to me?

Tags: dc, brushless-dc-motor

Drone pilot here, we use LiPo batteries and speed controls to brushless motors for flight.  My new electronics state that one should not use a power supply and only use a lipo for testing.

After some emails I learned that it is the regenerative breaking (active braking) that is causing issue here. I quote:

> "A Lipo can handle the Backward-Power during active Braking."

It was also recommended that I use "a ipo on the bench".  No idea on what an `ipo` is, yet? (might be a typo meaning "lipo?)

I understand the basics of regenerative breaking via the brushless motor, and the brushless motor operation.

My goal is to use a VERY MASSIVE 12v power supply for testing. (60a stable, burst into the hundreds. Yeah, it weighs like 50lbs and cost a lot of $) I don't want to hurt the speed control (http://kiss.flyduino.net/kiss-esc-24a-re/) and seem to not be able to get a clear answer from the vendor yet.

Regardless of their answer, I think it is important for me to get some instruction on what backward flow is and add some droplets to the kill bucket.

Comment: It means you can charge the battery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter how big a current your big supply can deliver, under braking, the ESC is feeding power back into whatever is supplying it. A battery can take this power without its terminal voltage increasing much. A power supply, even a humungeous one, is probably not designed to expect a reverse flow of power into it, and its output voltage might rise dangerously, as it doesn't have the components in it to absorb that power, damaging the supply and/or the ESC.

If you supplied (say) 30 amps of auto bulbs with your 60A power supply, then you'd have 30A left to drive your motors. If the ESC sent 30A back into the supply when regernatively braking, the bulbs would be able to absorb the power (but no more than 30A).

A lower power alternative would be to shunt your supply with something capable of dumping the power if the voltage rose more than a volt or two. It might be possible to find transorbs with pass/stop voltages close enough, or you could build something with darlingtons and zener diodes as an active clamp.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense and was what I was thinking. Considerably more concise with a good breakdown, great for us drone guys who are clearly EE hacks. I am considering trickle charging a battery for bench use (parallel example of a 12v car battery on a solar panel w/cutoff).  A few simple precautions would make things very safe as the goal is to have consistent and available power for builds and tests with out needing to manage battery status as well.

Comment: A car battery is perfect for bench use. Don't need to worry about the lower power to weight ratio than LiPos, can float it 24/7/365 at 13.8 volts without overcharging (we don't need no steeeenkin' charge control), and chances are you don't need a new one, might even get one or two free. One that has been retired from car service because it can't do the CCA may still do a heathly 60A from fully charged.